# Pass HTML attribute value to function in angular 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I have a custom element that I just want to show when I click a button. Then, when I click that button, I want to do something like...:

```
<my-element [hidden]="switchHidden()"></my-element>
```

... so if it's in false, it now will be true, and viceversa. A very typical approach.

But I don't know how I can pass to my function "switchHidden()" the value of the "hidden" attribute. How can I do this, so I can check whether it is true or false?

Thank you!

Comment: Is the button you want to click to hide show custom element, inside custom  element or outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/X2LvKArrm4v2wTUeYqE5?p=preview) Demo

Just have a variable in your component that is a boolean for when you want to show and hide it.

```
let showElement: Boolean = true;
```

Then when you want to toggle it on/off with a button put this in the click.

```
<button (click)="showElement = !showElement">Toggle</button>
```

and that will flip the value of `showElement` every time the user clicks the button. So if `showElement` is true, when the user clicks the button it will make `showElement` false and thus hidding your element. Vise versa for when `showElement` is false, the user clicks the button making it true and thus showing your element.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use hidden attribute, use:

```
<my-element *ngIf="switchHidden"></my-element>
```

http://angularjs.blogspot.ba/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Comment: That seems kinda stupid (sorry not meaning to be offensive), display:none, is so much more lightweight than creating and destroying DOM elements, if you have CSS problems, you can always add your own attribute CSS
`[hidden] {
display: none !important;
}`